# replacing column values with either 0 or NaN

Tags: awk, sed

I have many columns of data in a text file, in the same interval as well as randomly i want to replace some column values with zero/NaN.

My input file is

```
1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 2.0
5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 1.0
1.0 2.0 8.0 9.0 6.0
```

As i want to replace some columns values in regular interval at that time output should be

```
1.0 0.0 3.0 0.0 2.0
5.0 0.0 7.0 0.0 1.0
1.0 0.0 8.0 0.0 6.0
```

as my second condition is to replace the columns values with zero randomly at that time output should besomething like this

```
0.0 2.0 3.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 6.0 7.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 2.0 8.0 0.0 0.0
```

I tried the script

```
awk -F '\t' '{OFS="\t"; $2=0; print}' input.txt
```

However, it only does for second column, but i need to do it in regular interval and randomly.Please experts suggest a solution

Comment: When the `NaN` is used?

Comment: Sometimes i need to replace some columns with NaN values instead of zero

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is a _regular interval_? How do you specify this? Index of first column to zero and step between zeroed columns? Please explain and give an example specification. And what do you mean by _randomly_? Random column indexes but the same for all rows? Completely random? How many columns do you want to zero? Please explain and give an example specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1st condition:

```
awk '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) $i="0.0"} 1' input.txt
```

The 2nd condition:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (rand() < 0.5) $i="0.0"} 1' input.txt
```

The value `0.5` roughly controls the probability of the replacement.

Answer (score 2):

GNU `sed` solution for 1st case. Assuming your numbers are sheared by single space and `file.txt` content is

```
1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 2.0
5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 1.0
1.0 2.0 8.0 9.0 6.0
```

then

```
sed 's/\(\S\S*\) \S\S*/\1 0.0/g' file.txt
```

output

```
1.0 0.0 3.0 0.0 2.0
5.0 0.0 7.0 0.0 1.0
1.0 0.0 8.0 0.0 6.0
```

Explanation: I used capturing group to globally (`g`) replace (1 or more non-whitespaces), space, 1 or more non-whitespaces with what is before that space, space, `0.0`. If you would need to replace 3rd, 6th, 9th and so on columns with zeros this code can be altered as follows

```
sed 's/\(\S\S*\) \(\S\S*\) \S\S*/\1 \2 0.0/g' file.txt
```

output

```
1.0 2.0 0.0 4.0 2.0
5.0 6.0 0.0 8.0 1.0
1.0 2.0 0.0 9.0 6.0
```

*(tested in [GNU sed live editor](https://sed.js.org/))*